# Complexity of recursive algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm having hard time understanding time complexity of my solution for [combination sum problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum/). The problem is as follows:

> Given a set of candidate numbers (`candidates`) (without duplicates) and a target number (`target`), find all unique combinations in candidates where the candidate numbers sums to `target`.
>
> The same repeated number may be chosen from candidates unlimited number of times.

Below is my solution written in Java using recursion:

```
public List<List<Integer>> combinationSum(int[] candidates, int target) {
    Arrays.sort(candidates);
    List<List<Integer>> results = new ArrayList<>();
    recurse(results, candidates, target, 0, new ArrayList<>());
    return results;
}

private void recurse(List<List<Integer>> results, int[] candidates, int target, int idx, List<Integer> acc) {
    if (target == 0) {
        results.add(new ArrayList<>(acc));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = idx; i < candidates.length; i++) {
        if (candidates[i] > target) {
            return;
        }
        acc.add(candidates[i]); 
        recurse(results, candidates, target - candidates[i], i, acc);
        acc.remove(acc.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

One can observe that the problem size of each recursive step is potentially not changed and the depth of the recursion is bound by `target` value e.g. if the `candidates` array contains number 1 the recursion will happen `target` times. If I simplify the code the interesting part is:

```
private void recurse(List<List<Integer>> results, int[] candidates, int target, int idx, List<Integer> acc) {
    if (target == 0) {
        results.add(new ArrayList<>(acc));
        return;
    }
    for (int i = idx; i < candidates.length; i++) {
        acc.add(candidates[i]); 
        recurse(results, candidates, target - candidates[i], i, acc);
        acc.remove(acc.size() - 1);
    }
}
```

Which feels like `O(candidates.length * target)` for the most pessimistic `candidates` input with number 1.

Since my solution is not really a divide and conquer algorithm I guess that I can't apply [the master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). It feels like a  backtracking algorithm but I'm not familiar with finding upper bound for that type of algorithms.

Can someone please advise how to approach complexity analysis of above code?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious algorithm tries all subsets, i.e., is $O(2^n)$ if you have $n$ elements to select. And your algorithm does that (try with first element, try without first element).

Complexity is given by the recurrence:

$$T(n) = 2 T(n - 1), T(0) \text{ given}$$

(try two posibilities for first one, recurse on the $n - 1$ others for each).